# Can I power multiple stepper motors from a bench power supply without issue?

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor

I'm trying to create a CNC machine as a practical implementation of what I've been learning in electronics. I want to be able to power multiple stepper motors (Nema 17s via rasp pi and driver), some kits come with a power supply included but I'm wondering if a bench power supply would be a better investment so I can use it to test other applications as I'm learning.

I don't have much electronics equipment at the moment and I'd rather not wast money on buying power supplies for each stepper if a more versatile and quality bench power supply would do.

Can I run multiple stepper motors from one bench power supply without issue, and are there any limitations or issues I should be aware of?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A bench PSU costs 500+, while you didn't listed Nr of axes and power required.

Comment: That is impossible to answer as it is required to know how much motors consume current and whether or not the power supply can provide more than what motors require.

Answer (score 2):

Any $25 brick will do too. But these tend to be noisy flyback types. Yet I found a very useful $60 PSU with digital V and I limit controls and displays Pout too,  for testing batteries, LED's etc from Banggood.

So earth grounding may help with parasitics on USB from high CM noise on both interfaces (PC & uC/stepper) or No PE just floating with a laptop. Just a warning on EMI issues with earthed towers and USB interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may run multiple stepper motors from one bench power supply without issues.

Just make sure that your power supply is able to deliver all the required current plus an extra 30% as a margin.

During tests, use a scope to monitor the output voltage of that power supply that should remain stable. You will see some drops but they are fine as long as they are smaller than 5/10 % of the actual output voltage.